# using exists clause in a sum case (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, exists, case-when

I'm trying to avoid a very expensive join between two tables: I'm wondering if it's possible by using the EXISTS clause since I don't need to show any field from the second table.
The code, at this moment is:

```
SELECT
t1.year, t1.month,
sum(case when (t1.flag1=0 and **t2.flag2=1**) then 1 else 0 end) as sum1
sum(case when (t1.flag1=1 and **t2.flag2=0**) then 1 else 0 end) as sum2
FROM
t1
**RIGHT JOIN t2 on (t1.uk1 = t2.uk2)**
GROUP BY
t1.year, t1.month
```

I haven't worked out any possible solution yet and I'm wondering if somebody know how to do it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that `uk2` is a unique key in `t2`, so you just need to find if there exists a row with `t2.uk2 = t1.uk1` and `t2.flag = 1` then the joining can stop - no need to continue?

If so:

```
SELECT
t1.year, t1.month,
sum(case when t1.flag1=0 and 
              t1.uk1 in (select t2.uk2 from t2 where t2.flag = 1)
              then 1 else 0 end)
FROM
t1
GROUP BY
t1.year, t1.month
```

Note though that a semi-join (using IN or EXISTS) will save some time, but not too much. It's not the entire join but it is still a partial join; you can't avoid that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution.
I Tried to implement it and instead of "in" I think I can use "=".
Unfortonately I've realized soon that just at one point of the query I need to compute this
    sum(decode(t2.flag2, 1, 1, 0))
I don't know if the solution you suggested still works in this case (if yes please let me know!!)
Anyway your solution will be very usefull in many other situations. Thank you again!